# To use a variable defined in a function

Tags: python, function

Hello all…a newbie question if you don’t mind.

Like below:

```
def plus_it(a, b):
    result = a + b
    if result == 0:
        aa = '0'
        #print aa    an option here
    else:
        aa = 'the result is ' + str(result)
        #print aa    an option here

plus_it(5, 6)
print aa
```

I can add on print ‘aa’ lines inside the function. However if I want to use the ‘aa’ outside the function like above, it gives an error:

```
NameError: name 'aa' is not defined
```

How can I use the ‘aa’ outside the function?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't and that's a Good Thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `return` statement and assign the returned value to `aa`:

```
def plus_it(a, b):
    result = a + b
    if result == 0:
        return '0'
    else:
        return 'the result is ' + str(result)

aa = plus_it(5, 6)
print aa
```

Comment: thanks! it's easy to understand and effective.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `aa` outside the function. The variable `aa` has a local scope.
You have two options:

- Return a value from your function and use it outside
- Use  a global variable

> ```
> aa = 0
> def plus_it(a, b):
>     global aa
>     aa = 'value'
> ```